# .htaccess rewrite URL to simulated subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite the URL from

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?page=SOMEPAGE&user=SOMEUSER
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/settings/user/SOMEUSER
```

where `settings` is the page parameter from the URL. My Solution was:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/user/([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?page=$1&user=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The problem is, that all files respond with a 404 error code, because the browser seems to think that `/settings/user` are actual folders on the server. How can I achieve that the actual URL path stays the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would seem to be that you are using *relative* URLs to your resources. If you are changing the path depth of your URLs then you need to ensure you are using either root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute (with a scheme + hostname) URLs throughout.

See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) on the following question on the Webmasters SE site for more information:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

> because the browser seems to think that /settings/user are actual folders on the server.

No, the browser sees that as the URL-path. It IS the URL-path as seen in the browser. Any relative client-side URLs are going to be relative to this URL-path. The browser has non concept of what are server-side folders, it only deals with URLs.

> How can I achieve that the actual URL path stays the same?

You are changing the URL-path in the browser, so the only way round this is to make your URLs non-relative.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer worked perfectly fine! :)